# How can I map a continuous variable to discrete strings, using dictionaries or otherwise in Python?

Tags: python, dictionary, range

I have a continuous variable with a min value of 0 and a max value of 1.  Therefore this includes all the float numbers from 0 to 1 inclusive.

I want to be able to map 0-0.2 to 'very low', 0.2-0.4 to 'low', 0.4-0.6 to 'medium', 0.6-0.8 to 'high' and 0.8 to 1.0 to 'very high'.

I assume that there is a simple solution to this using dictionaries.  However, I am having trouble generating a the continuous ranges as keys.  It seems possible that if the ranges were discrete integers then I could just use the range function.

For example:

```
range_dict = {range(0,2):'very low',range(2,4):'low',range(4,6):'medium',
range(6,8):'high',range(8,10):'high'}
```

However, when attempting the following:

```
range_dict[1]
```

I expect to receive 'very low'.  However, I just get a KeyError despite 1 being in the range(0,2).

Writing this as

```
1 in range(0,2)
```

does return True.

Anyway, back to the original problem where I am dealing with a continuous variable!

I am sure there is a simple solution to this, but it obviously requires a different approach!  First, is there a range function to account for continuous rather than discrete variables?  Second, perhaps another problem here is precisely that dictionaries cannot map multiple to one?  Thanks...

---

Another way to approach it would be to write an if, elif, else style function covering all the bins and returning the string at the appropriate point in the function, but I am looking specifically for a solution involving using a dictionary (since the dictionary seems a clearer way to read this within the code).  Thanks again...

Comment: `1` is in `range(0, 2)`, but `1` is not `range(0, 2)`.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The [bisect](https://docs.python.org/3.5/library/bisect.html) module has a nice way to handle this. See under *Other Examples* in the link above:

```
from bisect import bisect

def category(fl, breakpoints=[.2,.4, .6, .8, 1.1], cat=['very low', 'low', 'medium', 'high', 'very high']):
        return cat[bisect(breakpoints, fl)]

category(.15)  # very low
category(.2)   # low
category(.99)  # very high
category(.5)   # medium
```

Comment: I was just about to mention the upper breakpoint needs to be higher than 1.0 for it to include 1.0!  Thanks for the edit!  You beat me to it.  This is a good solution, although I would prefer to see the dictionary mapping more explicitly.  Having the two lists separated like that is somewhat harder to read.

Comment: Yeah @agftrading the upper limit here is non-inclusive so if you pass it something larger than the top limit it will give an index of 5, which is greater than the number of categories. Another solution is to leave it at 1.0 and include another category for all values greater than or equal to 1.0. that can also be `very high`

Comment: Unless you need a pure import-less solution, I think this answer is better than mine!

Answer (score 2):

I would do this instead, taking advantage of the fact that your bins are the same width:

```
values = [v / 10 for v in range(10)]  # [0.0, 0.1...0.9]
binned = [value // 0.2 for value in values]

mapping = {0: 'very low',
           1: 'low',
           2: 'medium',
           3: 'high',
           4: 'very high'}

result = [mapping[bin] for bin in binned]
print(result)
```

Output:

```
['very low', 'very low', 'low', 'low', 'medium', 'medium', 'medium', 'high', 'very high', 'very high']
```

Answer (score 0):

There is a nice way to discretize continuous values using Pytorch:

```
import torch

num_values = 10
num_buckets = 3

continuous = torch.rand(num_values)

# bucket continous actions into discrete actions
boundaries = torch.linspace(start=0, end=1, steps=num_buckets+1)
discrete = torch.bucketize(continuous, boundaries)

print(continuous)
print(discrete)
```